# Zuul route for single resource

Tags: java, netflix-zuul

I have two endpoints and a gateway (zuul proxy).

- mydomain.de <- Zuul proxy
- api.mydomain.de <- REST endpoints
- portal.mydomain.de <- serving .html page

All requests schould be routet to one endpoint except the request for a single .html page.
All request should be accessed through the toplevel path mydomain.de.

My zuul config looks like the following:

```
       zuul:
   routes:
       index:
       path: /index.html
       sensitive-headers:
       url: portal.mydomain.de/index.html
    core:
       path: /**
       sensitive-headers:
       url: api.mydomain.de
```

Now requesting mydomain.de/index.html leads to a 404 and is routet to REST endpoint api.mydomain.de.
Isn't it possible with to define a resource as route and does it always have to be a true path?

Comment: is there a possibility that you can make the api.mydomain.de route to something else, like `api`? then the portal would be `path: /**` , while the api would be as `path: /api`

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it not. For me the question is, if it is in principle possible to have a route like /index.html or if it has to be a path an not a direct resource?